# Asymptotic approximation of binomial theorem

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, computer-science, binomial-theorem, approximation-theory

Binomial theorem is a very popular theorem that:
$$(x + y) ^ n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}x^i y^{n-i}$$

I am looking for any papers (the newer the better) where I can find any informations about asymptotic approximation of the binomial theorem, especially for the case when I have $(1 + y)^n$. 
[Here](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/40asymptotic/) I found the approximation, that the asymptotic approximation of $(1+x)^k$ is $1 + kx + {k \choose 2}x^2 + {k \choose 3}x^3 + O(x^4)$. But maybe are any works where I can find more accurate approximation?

Comment: Asymptotic in what sense?  $y \to 0$?  $y \to \infty$?  $y$ fixed and $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas $y\rightarrow 0$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: At the same time?  Or separately?  If you want them to go at the same time, how do their rates compare?  e.g. is $ny \approx 1$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, in the same time and yes, $ny \approx 1$

Comment: If $y \approx 1/n$ then $(1+y)^n \approx (1+1/n)^n \approx e$ for large $n$.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I see that your answear is correct, but unfortunatelly I am looking for something more accurate, like in my example

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotic approximation you have is just binomial expansion up to the 4th term. What happens as $n \to \infty$ depends on $y$. If $y$ is a constant larger than $0$, the sum diverges, if $-1<y<0$ it converges to 0. If $y= \frac{a}{n}$, the limit is of course $e^a$. Hence, no single answer exists.

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned in the comments that the author is seeking an approximation in the case that $n \to \infty$ and $y \approx 1/n$.  One approach is to set $y = \frac{1+z}{n}$, so that the expression is

$$
\left(1 + \frac{1+z}{n}\right)^n.
$$

Then we can expand the function

$$
f(a,b) = (1 + (1+a)b)^{1/b}
$$

in [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) about the point $(a,b) = (0,0)$, obtaining

$$
f(a,b) = e \left(1 + a - \frac{b}{2} + \frac{a^2}{2} - \frac{3ab}{2} + \frac{11 b^2}{24} + O(3)\right),
$$

where $O(3)$ represents terms of cubic order.  Taking $a = ny-1$ and $b = 1/n$ we arrive at the approximation

$$
\left(1 + y\right)^n \approx e \left(\frac{1+n^2y^2}{2}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{3 y}{2}+\frac{11}{24 n^2}\right).
$$

By the same method, an approximation including the third order terms is

$$
\left(1 + y\right)^n \approx e \left( \frac{2+3ny+n^3y^3}{6}+\frac{5}{12 n}-\frac{7 n y^2}{12}-\frac{y}{3}-\frac{7}{36 n^2}+\frac{47 y}{72 n}-\frac{7}{16 n^3} \right).
$$